# Installing texlive without root permissions from the source files

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

Working on a Linux machine, I've run across some issues which seem like they're due to the fact that I installed **texlive** with

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

I'm trying to re-install **texlive** from the source files.  I've downloaded and decompressed them, and I'm hoping not to use root permissions in part because the instruction site suggests that it's best not to do so.  However, when I executed:

```
./install-tl
```

I got the error:

> ./install-tl: mkdir(/usr/local/texlive/) failed: Permission denied at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 913,  line 1.

Presumably the issue is that although I executed `install-tl` from the directory in which I have write permissions, it's also trying to make files in `usr/local/texlive/` in which I need to be root in order to write to that directory.  I'm stuck. Do I need to be root to do this?

Comment: I guess it would be against the spirits of all the user system if something set up by an admin can be drastically modified by an "ordinary" user. What you should do will depend a bit on how much you trust the maintainers of TeXLive and their ability to prevent harm from the update manager. (I personally do my updates as superuser even though I am the only user on my computer, but I can see why others may not want to do that.) I guess you are left with the options of either removing the existing installation as admin and then try again, or to update in the admin mode.

Comment: If you want to install in the default place then you need sudo. As I'm the only user on my system I install in /opt/texlive after I created that folder and made me the owner. You can also create a dedicated user to own latex and just update latex using that user (there are some benefits from that, especially on multiuser systems). Just remember to add the new path in the correct way (I do not recommend having install-tl create softlinks, you'll forget you made then and get confused later on)

Comment: @marmot My concern wasn't really security, it was just that the site said that it's best not to install with root permissions:  https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html  But since it seemed like people were saying it's basically not possible to install without being root I went ahead and used sudo anyway.  Now when I try to enter `tlmgr update --all` it gives a permission error and when I try it with sudo, it says it doesn't understand the command.  I'm guessing this is why it was a bad idea to install as root.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you here, I am afraid. Of course, I can understand how frustrated you are, I also had some problems some time because I had used two different installers. Finally @egreg fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to choose the option `D` and then to specify your user directory. Then you return to the main options with `R`  and subsequently choose `I` to install.

Comment: This helped me a lot! The default dir installation is /usr/local/texlive/2020 which is not writeable by non-sudoer users. I was initially able to install tex live in this default location prefixing `sudo` but I had problems in my installation. Removing everything and resintalling from scratch specifying a directory in my user home was the correct (and recocmended) way. +1

Comment: @umbe1987 Glad that I could be of assistance :-)